# Set notation check

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the three statements:

- $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^3$
- $\{a,b,c\}\subset\mathbb{Q}$
- $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Q}$

equivalent ways of saying that a, b and c are rational numbers?

Comment: Be careful with the second one. Notice that $\emptyset \subset \mathbb{Q}$, but otherwise, yes.

Comment: yes, though the second can be occasionally misunderstood to imply that $a\neq b$, $a\neq c$, and $b\neq c$ since it is rare to see a set with elements repeated (it shouldn't imply it though).  For an unordered set, the sets $\{1,1,1,5\}$ and $\{1,5\}$ are in fact considered the same thing.

Comment: I really do not thing they are equivalent, it is true that they all are telling they are indeed rational numbers but you are putting somehow relations on them. In the first 2 you are relating the numbers and you are, in a sense, establishing some "order" in the first 1.

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, they are equivalent. From a communication point of view (which is what matters, in my opinion), they are not equivalent. If you write either the first or the second one, the reader's reaction will probably be "Why did he write it that strange way? What subtle unstated message is he trying to convey?". Be nice to your readers; use the third alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q} $ simply says that $ a, b, c $ are rational.
$ \{ a, b, c \} \subset \mathbb{Q} $ says more or less the same thing but also creates a particular subset of $ \mathbb{Q} $. $ (a, b, c) \in \mathbb{Q}^3 $ may refer to an ordered pair in the space $ \mathbb{Q}^3 $.
So in summary, perhaps $ a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q} $ is the simplest statement, whereas the others say a little bit more.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify - does $\{a,b,c\}$ not exist before I specify it?

Comment: I wonder if that question is philosophical :) ..but I was speaking in the more mundane sense of having specified a set, that may perhaps be referenced later